# Swaping images of two imageView not workng properly in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have made a demo for filmstrip in Android. I have taken 9 `ImageView`s in a `LinearLayout`, set images to them. However, I am getting an old bitmap while swapping the second time. What am I missing?

```
void swap(ImageView iv1, ImageView iv2) {
    iv1.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = iv1.getDrawingCache();

    iv2.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b2 = iv2.getDrawingCache();

    iv2.setImageBitmap(b1);
    iv1.setImageBitmap(b2);
    tempView.clear();
    iv_image_1.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_2.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_3.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_4.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_5.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_6.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_7.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_8.postInvalidate();
    iv_image_9.postInvalidate();
}
```